# Why does if( -8 & 7) return false

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

When i try to run the following code it prints "FALSE" instead of "TRUE"
Can somebody explain why the code returns false?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    if(-8 & 7)
    {
        printf("TRUE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FALSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why were you expecting it to return true?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the `&` operator (as opposed to the `&&` operator)? Do you know the standard binary representation of the integer 7? What [common representations for negative numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) exist? What's common today? What's the binary representation of -8 in it?  If you answer these basic questions you can answer your specific question here (and all others like it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

-8 can be represented the following way ( I will use a byte representation

```
8  = 00001000
~8 = 11110111
-8 = 11111000 (~8 + 1)
```

That is `-8` in the two-complement representation is equal tp `~8 + 1`

So `-8` is equal to `11111000` and `7` is equal to `00000111`

```
11111000
&
00000111
========
00000000
```

that is the binary AND operation yields a false result.

Answer (score 0):

`7` is represented as `00000111` in binary. `-8` is represented as `11111000` in binary. The bitwise AND operation performs an AND on every bit:

```
00000111
&
11111000
=
00000000
```

Hence, the if condition is false.